# Mechanical Turk submit not displaying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

I am using the Turkee Gem in a rails 4 app, trying to send custom HITs to the requestersanbox. It seems that the response from the form submission cannot be displayed in an iframe because of the response header 'X-Frame-Options'.
I ran into the same console error when trying to get my hit to display - but since the hit was hosted server side it was easy to change the header. How do I stop mturk from sending this form header, or is it something I need to do server side?

```
Refused to display 'https://workersandbox.mturk.com/mturk/externalSubmit' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
```

displays in my console on submitting the form in the request sandbox.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can do anything in MTurk to change this. HITs are supposed to be submitted via browser-based POST in order to avoid exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. The form within the iframe is posting to: https://workersandbox.mturk.com/mturk/externalSubmit. whatever is displayed in the iframe after that post is not showing up. is the result of submitting the form supposed to come from my app or mechanical turk? If my app how do I set that route?

Comment: Sorry, maybe you're not doing what I thought you were doing. This kind of error would typically come if you try to do a server-side POST operation to the submit URL rather than redirecting the worker via the browser to that URL. That is, you have to send the worker via the browser to the submit URL (and not in an iframe).

Comment: Sorry, how can I send the worker via the browser to the submit url not in an iframe if MT is hosting my form in an iframe. The way the ruby gem is set up, any everything I have read about doing MT with rails says you host a form from your app that MT hosts in an iframe, and that form posts to their url. Or am I completely misunderstanding something?

Comment: Can you include a link to your HIT in the worker sandbox (or the details for being able to search for it)? Or, if you don't want to share your full HIT, a small example that produces this error?

Comment: Thank you for all the help, the problem was that I was trying to complete my own tasks from the requester sanbox for testing, that is apparently not possible. You need to log into the worker sandbox and complete your hits. again thanks